# Average of column B values per column A value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mean

Goal: Append column `Mean` with the same average value propagated per column `Model`.

I want to append the `mean` of each `Model`'s `Time` scores.

The `Mean` value should be the same, per `Model`.

`df` is already in this grouped order.

`df`:

```
Model | Time
-------------
bert | 0.0001432
bert | 0.0001123
mlp | 0.2321
mlp | 0.2324
```

Desired `df`:

```
Model | Time | Mean
-------------------
bert | 0.0001432 | 0.00012775
bert | 0.0001123 | 0.00012775
mlp | 0.2321 | 0.23225
mlp | 0.2324 | 0.23225
```

---

**Code:**

```
models = df.Model.unique()
mean = df.groupby('a')['b'].mean()
for m in models:
    sums[m]

df2 = df.assign(Average = mean)
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I can add to post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform('mean')` instead of `mean()` to broadcast values on each row:

```
df['Mean'] = df.groupby('Model').transform('mean')
print(df)

# Output
  Model      Time      Mean
0  bert  0.000143  0.000128
1  bert  0.000112  0.000128
2   mlp  0.232100  0.232250
3   mlp  0.232400  0.232250
```

Values are not rounded:

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:,.10f}'.format):
    display(df)

# Output:
  Model         Time         Mean
0  bert 0.0001432000 0.0001277500
1  bert 0.0001123000 0.0001277500
2   mlp 0.2321000000 0.2322500000
3   mlp 0.2324000000 0.2322500000
```