# How to add average value of value column by every unique id column?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm attempting to do something very similar to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70596044/average-of-column-b-values-per-column-a-value), but I need to use pyspark dataframes and I'm looking to create two columns based off different IDs.

Essentially I am attempting to append my original pyspark dataframe with two news columns each containing the mean value for their paired IDs.

An example initial df and the output df can be found below:

[Example input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYWmr.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670958/spark-dataframe-computing-row-wise-mean-or-any-aggregate-operation

Comment: Question needs some code:
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this , you need to create 2 individual dataframes containing the the aggregation and join it to back to the original dataframe.

> Essentially I am attempting to append my original pyspark dataframe
> with two news columns each containing the mean value for their paired
> IDs.

### Data Preparation

```
d = {
        'id1':[1]*2 + [2] * 3,
        'id2':[2]*2 + [1] * 3,
        'value': [i for i in range(1,100,20)]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+---+---+-----+
|id1|id2|value|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  2|    1|
|  1|  2|   21|
|  2|  1|   41|
|  2|  1|   61|
|  2|  1|   81|
+---+---+-----+
```

### Aggregation & Join

```
sparkDF_agg_id1 = sparkDF.groupBy('id1').agg(F.mean(F.col('value')).alias('value_mean_id1'))
sparkDF_agg_id2 = sparkDF.groupBy('id2').agg(F.mean(F.col('value')).alias('value_mean_id2'))

finalDF = sparkDF.join(sparkDF_agg_id1
                       ,sparkDF['id1'] == sparkDF_agg_id1['id1']
                       ,'inner'
                  ).select(sparkDF['*']
                        ,sparkDF_agg_id1['value_mean_id1']
                  )

finalDF = finalDF.join(sparkDF_agg_id2
                       ,finalDF['id2'] == sparkDF_agg_id2['id2']
                       ,'inner'
                  ).select(finalDF['*']
                        ,sparkDF_agg_id2['value_mean_id2']

                )
                           
finalDF.show()

+---+---+-----+--------------+--------------+
|id1|id2|value|value_mean_id1|value_mean_id2|
+---+---+-----+--------------+--------------+
|  2|  1|   41|          61.0|          61.0|
|  2|  1|   61|          61.0|          61.0|
|  2|  1|   81|          61.0|          61.0|
|  1|  2|    1|          11.0|          11.0|
|  1|  2|   21|          11.0|          11.0|
+---+---+-----+--------------+--------------+
```